# Access sqlite3 variable in different classes

Tags: objective-c, database, sqlite, global-variables

I have multiple classes in my project. When the application launches, a database is created in the app delegate. I need to access this database in another class, so I created an object (called Delegate) of the app delegate in this other class. Normally, to open the database, I will do something like

```
if(sqlite3_open([Delegate.databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
```

However, in this case, the variable database is global and is not in its parent class. How can I open my database in this case? I have tried

```
if(sqlite3_open([Delegate.databasePath UTF8String], &Delegate->database) == SQLITE_OK) //error: instance variable  database is protected
```

and

> if (sqlite3_open([Delegate.databasePath UTF8String], &Delegate.database) == SQLITE_OK) //Error: Address of property expression requested

But none of these work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either put your database instance variable in the app delegate or use a "singleton pattern".

(But I gather you may be confused by the nature of the "database" operand.  It's declared as a `sqlite3 **` in the method declaration, and should be the address of a `sqlite3 *` pointer.  Your attempts to pass the parm are thwarted because fields of an Objective-C class aren't normally public, and you can't take the address of a property.  The simplest (though somewhat crude) way around this for your case is to have a method that returns the address of the `sqlite3 *` variable (eg, `return &mySqlite3Variable`) from wherever your Delegate class is storing it.)